# Is there a way to find out what App Store the user is connected to?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I'm planning to release my app as a free version, and then let the user buy the full version through in app purchase. I'd like to customise the artwork so thats if they're on the UK Store it says "Buy full version for 59p" and on the US Store "Buy full version for $1". Is there any easy way to get this information? I know NSLocale can provide this information, but from what I can gather, this can be set to any country, and not necessarily the App Store that the user is connected to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the ["Retrieving Product Information"](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/RetrievingStoreInformation/RetrievingStoreInformation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH2-SW1) section of the In App Purchase Programming Guide, the process of retrieving information about your product from the App Store is described.  The SKProduct object that you get back from the store for the particular element to be purchased includes the price and priceLocale properties, which could be used to construct the localized price of your full version.

You might have to be careful with how you place this pricing information within the application, because many people (including myself) have have applications or updates rejected due to pricing information being presented to the user at some point in our free versions.  Things might take a little while to settle down after this change in the in-application purchase policy.

Comment: Ok, thanks very much. I'll leave it out for now, and I'll just present it to the user through the actual app purchase.